# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > -1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I run, make, or clean project,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> -1
```

this error message comes out.

I've checked my resource files several times, and there was no fatal error.
There are only png icons and xml files.

I don't know what the '-1' means..

And in my main java files, there are 'cannot resolve symbol R' errors.

My app have launched well last night, but when I wake up and run android studio this morning, it failed.

What should I do?

Here is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


 android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.exapmle.rantalk"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'}
```

Here below, I added my entire gradle output, thanks.

Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > -1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.62 secs

Comment: Try to clean android studio by: Click File choose Invalidates Cache/Restart then choose Invalidates cache and Restart.

Comment: Can you please show more of the Gradle output?

Comment: @cricket_007 I added it on my post, thanks.

Comment: @sonnv1368 I've tried many times.. but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get back to this. You could've tried `Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output`

Answer (score 3):

:app:mergeDebugResources may be thrown due to an issue with your resource file check in your drawables/resources whether you have numerical or caps in the name

Comment: I have image named "ic_chatting_white_24dp.png". Is it problem?

Comment: remove 24dp and rebuild the project  (numbers are  not allowed in drawable folder )

Comment: I removed all 24dp, and threre are no number and capitals in my resources... but it still don't work.

Comment: did you rebuild the app??

Comment: Of course. I cleaned project, rebuild project, invalidate&restart android studio and even reboot my computer.

Comment: Try this  `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output` to debug exactly where you are getting the error from

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm find that my styles.xml file has a problem...
I deleted styles and remake it, now my app works.
thanks for comments, guys.